# Python: `python DT22logger.py` error using PUTTY

Tags: python, putty, database

I have done configuring some of the commands in making the **DHT22 Temperature Sensor** work.

I have done configuring some codes in `config.json` now I am up to this `python DHT22logger.py` but I am getting this error (refer below)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DHT22logger.py", line 422, in <module>
    main()
  File "DHT22logger.py", line 251, in main
    configurations = getConfigurations()
  File "DHT22logger.py", line 243, in getConfigurations
    configurations = json.loads(open(configurationFile).read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 21 column 2 (char 347)
```

There is a tutorial that I have been following, when he write this `python DHT22logger.py` no errors, and the datas are in there. But in my case none.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your configuration file.

Python, rather helpfully, tells you where.

`line 21 column 2 (char 347)`

Comment: I've been in `sudo vim DHT22logger.py` in line 21 "there is nothing" just blank.

Comment: @pjforum That suggests that more data is expected, i.e. your JSON is malformed.

Comment: there is a tutorial that I have followed and for him everything works perfect!! I don't know why, I just followed his steps thoroughly.

Comment: @pjforum What does "I have done configuring some codes in config.json" mean?

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  1031 Feb 17 00:25 config.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 17671 Feb 17 00:44 DHT22logger.py`

Comment: @pjforum Have you made any changes to any of the configuration files?  If so that is where the error will be.

Comment: I have not... I just `git clone` from here "https://github.com/jjpFin/DHT22-TemperatureLogger" and made no changes...

Comment: @pjforum I have just cloned the git and it runs past that part on my Pi.  It complains about SMTP.

Comment: Oh it did? I think if you follow this steps I don't think it will run past that.. "http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-and-DHT22-temperature-and-humidity-lo/step10/Set-up-the-temperature-logger-code/"

Comment: @pjforum I have not changed the configuration and it runs past the configuration code.  You said you did not change the configuration so it should get to the same point.  IF you HAVE changed the configuration you have made an incorrect change.

Comment: I will try to revert changes and do it again..